# Need clipboard change listener for mac os using java

Tags: java, macos, clipboard, clipboarddata

Currently, I am doing a project where I need a clipboard change listener for macOS. I have FlavorListener which is working fine for Windows, but the same code is not working for macOS. How can I get this to work on macOS?

```java
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().addFlavorListener(new FlavorListener() {
    @Override
    public void flavorsChanged(FlavorEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getSource() + " " + e.toString());
    }
}
```